# Passing Multiple parameters from Custom WebPart to Reporting services Report Viewer webpart

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, web-parts

I working with Reporting services in Sharepoint Mode, I am able to show the report in Sql Server Reporting services report viewer , the report has multiple parameters , My question is how do I pass more than one parameter from a custom web part to this report.

I am able to pass one parameter by implementing the ITransformableFilterValues interface in the custom webpart , what I want to do is pass more than one parameter .

Ex: If there are 2 parameters on report then i should able to map each from the control in webpart.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the Code for Custom Webpart:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using aspnetwebparts = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
//using Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities;
using wsswebparts = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
//using Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace CustomWebPart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to provide filter values for the status report.
    /// </summary>
    public class StatusReportFiler : aspnetwebparts.WebPart, wsswebparts.ITransformableFilterValues
    {
        DropDownList ddlCategory;
        ListItem lstItem;
        Label lblCaption; 

        public virtual bool AllowMultipleValues
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public virtual bool AllowAllValue
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool AllowEmptyValue
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public virtual string ParameterName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Category";
            }
        }



        public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues
        {
            get
            {
                string[] values = this.GetCurrentlySelectedCategory();
                return values == null ?
                    null :
                    new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(values);
            }
        }


        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {


            lblCaption = new Label();
            lblCaption.Text = "&nbsp; Category:&nbsp;";

            Controls.Add(lblCaption);

            ddlCategory = new DropDownList();
            ddlCategory.AutoPostBack = true;

            lstItem = new ListItem();
            lstItem.Text = "Select All Category";
            lstItem.Value = "0";
            ddlCategory.Items.Add(lstItem);
            lstItem = null;


            lstItem = new ListItem();
            lstItem.Text = "BING";
            lstItem.Value = "Bing";
            ddlCategory.Items.Add(lstItem);
            lstItem = null;

            lstItem = new ListItem();
            lstItem.Text = "Google";
            lstItem.Value = "Google";
            ddlCategory.Items.Add(lstItem);
            lstItem = null;


            Controls.Add(ddlCategory);



           // base.CreateChildControls();
        }


        [aspnetwebparts.ConnectionProvider("Category Filter", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
        public wsswebparts.ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
        {
            return this;
        }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        public string[] GetCurrentlySelectedCategory()
        {
            string[] selCategory = new string[1];
            selCategory[0] = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
            return selCategory;
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter)
        {


            /*htmlWriter.Write("<table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">");
            htmlWriter.Write("<tr><td>");
            lblCaption.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            htmlWriter.Write("</td></tr>");
            htmlWriter.Write("<tr><td>");
            lblCaption.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            htmlWriter.Write("</td></tr>");
            htmlWriter.Write("</table>");*/

            this.EnsureChildControls();
            RenderChildren(htmlWriter);

        }

    }
}
```

1. Once you build this Webpart deploy it to SharePoint.
   Create a Webpart page in Sharpoint , Add the Custom Web Part to the page  .
   Once you add it you will be able to see the dropdownlist with values on the Webpart .
2. In another Add Webpart Section add a Sql Server Reporting Sevices ReportViewer web part and set the report URL in the properties section and click apply , this report should have the same parameter name as in Custom Webpart.
3. In the Custom Webpart click on Edit -> Connections-> Send Category Filter To -> ReportViewer - AAAA(This is the ReportName I Guess). This will popup a Window with the mapping section , Map the Filer Category to Filtered parameter on the Report and click Finish . This will pass the value from the Webpart to the Report.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about SharePoint integrated mode, but ReportServer correctly accept parameters passed via URL string.

Comment: If you have SharePoint Enterprise version, you can also use QueryString Filter web part to get the QueryString parameters and pass them to the SSRS web part. Or you can implement a custom QueryString FIlter Web Part doing the same.